# Autocomplete in windows application

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

How can i select value in textbox character by character Like HDPOS Autocomplete textbox

I tried 
**In Page Load**

```
private void loadproductName()
{
    DataTable dt = _poshelper.getproductName("Bill_Select_ProductName");
    if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        string[] postSource = dt
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Select<System.Data.DataRow, String>(x => x.Field<String>("UniqueName"))
                .ToArray();

        var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        source.AddRange(postSource);
        txtItemName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
    }     
}
```

**In Leave**

```
private void txtItemName_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtItemName.Text))
    {
        DataSet ds1 = _poshelper.getproductNameExistWhileLeave(txtItemName.Text);
        if (ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            txtItemName.Text = "";
            txtItemName.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            loadLeave(ds1);
            txtItemName.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

I need to

If i delete a character using backspace it delete permanently

[image: a]

I need like 2 nd image if i delete mean i need that containt remain in textbox

[image: b]

**Update**

more clarification, from comments

> The String in the textbox it should not be deleted if i press back space Key. Instead it should select each character.Every time i press backspace

Comment: Can you explain your requirement little more! I am not getting you completely! what do you want to do here by "select value in textbox character by character"

Comment: The String in the textbox it should not be deleted if i press back space Key. Instead it should select each character.Every time i press backspace

Comment: Your question was hard to understand, still I have answered, try it out and let me know if it is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm suggesting changes to make your textbox carry following behavior.

When you don't want **"appended suggestion"** text (as shown in first image) to be gone when you type backspace in text box,

you can do it these steps

- Get Current Textbox text (removed last character as we have back spaced lastly)
- Clear Text's Text
- Send Text taken text back to textbox

do following change in your code

```
private void loadproductName()
{
  DataTable dt = _poshelper.getproductName("Bill_Select_ProductName");
  if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
  {
    string[] postSource = dt
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select<System.Data.DataRow, String>(x => x.Field<String>("UniqueName"))
            .ToArray();

    var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    source.AddRange(postSource);
    txtItemName.AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
    txtItemName.AutoCompleteSource = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    txtItemName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what you are doing in `Leave` Event. But you can add `textBox`'s `KeyUp` event, and add code like below in that event.

```
private void txtItemName_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // track for backspace
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)
    {
        if (txtItemName.Text != "")
        {
            string text = txtItemName.Text.Substring(0, txtItemName.Text.Count() - 1);
            txtItemName.Text = "";
            txtItemName.Focus();
            SendKeys.Send(text);
        }
    }
}
```